# NestJS problem with entering secret key normally but not finding value

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs

I'm making JWT token inssuance function now.

but when i try to get token by login, the error occus like below:

`"Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value\n    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Node Projects\\stationzero_v2\\node_modules\\jsonwebtoken\\sign.js:105:20)\n    at JwtService.sign (C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Node Projects\\stationzero_v2\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\jwt\\dist\\jwt.service.js:35:20)\n    at AuthService.tokenIssuance (C:\\Users\\Tony\\Desktop\\Node Projects\\stationzero_v2\\src\\auth\\auth.service.ts:19:41)"`

this is my project dir

```
src
┗auth
  ┗jwt
    ┗jwt.gurad.ts
    ┗jwt.strategy.ts
    ┗jwt.payload.ts
  auth.module.ts
  auth.service.ts
  auth.service.spec.ts
```

I'am sure that I did a right way to put secret key into the `auth.module.ts`

```
//auth.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { PrismaService } from 'prisma/prisma.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt/jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports:[
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy : 'jwt', session : true}),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'test',
      signOptions: { expiresIn : '9h' }
    })
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, PrismaService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and this is `jwt.strategy.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Payload } from './jwt.payload';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy){
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: 'test'
        })
    }

    async validate(payload: Payload){
        return { email:payload.email, phone:payload.phone};
    }
}
```

this is the result when i tried by postman program
[image]

I even tried put secret key in the .env file, but it still requires secretOrPrivateKey...
can someone help me to solve this problem??
I don't know what is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when I see this error it is due to adding the `JwtService` to a `providers` array, either instead of only using the `JwtModule.register()` in an imports array, or alongside using the `JwtModule`.

When the `JwtService` is added directly to a `providers` array, Nest creates an instance of the `JwtService` and that instance will not be aware of the ptions given to the `JwtModule`, so when `sign` is called, there's no `secret`for it to use.

Answer (score 0):

my case is to create a `jwtConfig.class.ts` file:

```
import { JwtOptionsFactory, JwtModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JwtConfig implements JwtOptionsFactory {
  createJwtOptions(): JwtModuleOptions {
    return {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    };
  }
}
```

and import into a module like this:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useClass: JwtConfig,
    }),
```